# Ruby on Rails secrets.yml not added to .gitignore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

If Rails 4+ has **secret.yml**, where you can store API keys, why doesn't it automatically be added to the **.gitignore** file?

This is what my file looks like when creating a new app:

```
# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*
/tmp/*
!/log/.keep
!/tmp/.keep

# Ignore Byebug command history file.
.byebug_history
```

(by the way, I'm trying out Rails 5, but I think this question still applies)

Answer (score -1):

Its not added to `.gitignore` automatically. If you want you can add it yourself though.

Here is an [article](http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/20/a-better-way-to-manage-the-rails-secret-token/) with **additional information** about `secret.yml` which might be of any use.